# Load multicurrency by csv Prestashop

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I want to add products by csv files with prices in hryvnas(ukrainian currency) and euros. My **main currency is hryvna**.

So euro prices should be converted to hryvnas. I know that it is a standard functionality, but how can I load products with euro prices?

Answer (score 0):

just loads a product price in csv is assigned to your default currency.

There is no user charging for other currencies. The CMS automatically converts the price for all other active currencies in your store

Comment: prices in hryvnas is unmuttable. prices in euros is muttable.